# Email on iPad not showing after some days

Tags: ipad, email

After a few days my older emails on iPad2 stop showing in the inbox.
Dont find any clue where they went.

Does the mail program store the older emails elsewhere? How can i show all the emails and not just the newer ones?

Comment: What kind of account do you have? Exchange? Gmail? Other? There are specific settings for Exchange mails.

Comment: Hotmail and my domain account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to:

```
Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars
```

Scroll down to the "Mail" section and look at "Show."  Mine is set to show the 50 most recent messages.  Maybe this is why older emails seem to disappear?  To test, try setting this to a higher value; it allows you to set it as high as 1000 messages.

Comment: I guess that is the reason. Is there any way i can see the older emails?

Comment: What happened when you set it to a 1000 messages?  Did older emails not appear then?

Comment: No... Older emails did not appear on ipad

Comment: First, go to Hotmail via your web browser.  Make sure that the "missing" emails are still available there.  (If you can't see them there, you won't be able to see them on your iPad.)  Second, how are you connecting your Mail app to your Hotmail account?  Are you using IMAP?  If not, try it with IMAP.  That should synchronize your Mail app with your account.

Answer (score 7):

If you have an Exchange account or even a Gmail account configured as an Exchange account, there is an option in the email settings for Exchange to only sync up to a certain number of days worth of email. By default, it it set to 3 days. You can change this by going to Settings > Mail, Contacts & Calendars, tap on the email account in question and change the "Mail Days to Sync" option from 3 days to whatever you desire (I use No Limit).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using hotmail and my domain account.